# Series name empty after setting it in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts, series

After setting the name of a series in an Excel chart sheet with

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = dat.Cells(1, 2)
```

the chart legend shows the current value of the referenced cell but the 'series name' field in the 'Edit series' dialog is empty. Changes to the cells value don't show up in the chart legend.

[image]

Any  advice on how to set the series name properly?

Comment: A sheet has no `SeriesCollection`-property. And what is `dat`? Are you using `Option Explicit` ? Has your code any `On Error Resume Next`- statements?

Comment: Probably needs to be set using a reference to the cell in formula style ... `"='Daten UVNIR'!A2"`.

Comment: @FunThomas Sorry, my fault. It is ActiveChart ofc.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your comment! That solved it. If you add how to easily convert the cell formula to a string, I'll gladly accept that as an answer. I tried `"= " &  CStr(dat.Cells(1,2).Formula)`, but without success.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to use a reference to the cell formula. You need a reference to the cell itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dat` is a Worksheet-Variable pointing to your data sheet:

```
Dim nameFormula As String
nameFormula = = "=" & "'" & dat.Name & "'" & "!" & "$B$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = nameFormula
```

`nameFormula` will now contain `"='Daten UVNIR'!$B$1"`. With that, the name of the series is set to the cell B1 and not a fixed string (I always recommend to use intermediate variables, it helps debugging).

---

I would strongly recommend not to use `ActiveChart`. Instead, use something like

```
Dim co As ChartObject, ch As Chart, ser As Series
Set co = dat.ChartObjects(1)
Set ch = co.Chart
Set ser = ch.SeriesCollection(1)
(...)
ser.Name = nameFormula
```

(you can use the *name* of the ChartObject instead of 1 as index)

**Update**: Haven't noticed that you are working with a Chart Sheet. In that case, use

```
Dim ser As Series
set ser = Sheets("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1)
```

Comment: @BigBen: You're right. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & dat.Cells(1, 2).Address(External:=True)
```